# Is it possible to export many Facebook Fans Pages as a CSV or EXCEL file?

Tags: export

Hi I want to export many facebook fans pages into CSV or EXCEL.
Like its fixed field avatar,fans page name,banner,about,information etc...

But I have no idea how to do it , someone has experienced it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an API and its documentation. [Facebook For Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks/)